# What's the main idea of Apache Ignite?

Tags: ignite

GC may free the memory and resources, how to make object reusable when cache is hited ?
I want to deploy Ignite with Spark, and I am confused by keeping object across multi-nodes. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once cache is populated, a simple Cache.get() operation will return the same object. You can take a look at the Data Grid documentation in Ignite: https://ignite.incubator.apache.org/features/datagrid.html

Also,Ignite comes with a Shared RDD implementation for sharing state across Spark jobs and applications. I think this is perhaps what you need: https://ignite.incubator.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html